# wrong return value from getmxrr() and checkdnsrr()

Tags: php, dns

The [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php) for `getmxrr($url, &$mxHosts)` states:

> Returns TRUE if any records are found; returns FALSE if no records were found or if an error occurred.

But for some domains (e.g. *www.yahoo.com, example.com.com*) it just returns *true* but the return parameter `$mxHosts` is empty. Both domains do not have an MX record. `checkdnsrr()` returns *true*, either.

I compared the DNS entries of those domains and noticed that both have a CNAME entry while other domains that i tested and where the functions work fine do not have it.

Why are `getmxrr()` and `checkdnsrr()` giving wrong result values? Does this have anything to do with the CNAME?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
getmxrr ('yahoo.com', $out);
print_r($out);

$a = checkdnsrr('yahoo.com', 'MX');
var_dump($a);

Array
(
    [0] => mta7.am0.yahoodns.net
    [1] => mta5.am0.yahoodns.net
    [2] => mta6.am0.yahoodns.net
)
bool(true)
```

You are right, you must enter domain root without any www.

```
<?php
getmxrr ('www.yahoo.com', $out);
print_r($out);

Array
(
)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Yes, but if you use your program on www.google.com, it works. And www.google.com is no domain root, either.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: I have tried www.google.com but it doesnt worked. It showed me null. Then i tried as Akam mentioned(w/o www.) and it worked like charm.

Comment: @BhavikShah: As i tried to explain in the question: The content of $mxHosts (or $out in Akam's answer) is always correct. www.yahoo.com has no MX -> empty; yahoo.com has some -> you get the result. The problem is the return value of the function. It returns true, when it should return false because the is no MX record.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: Oh yes. I got it now. I mis-interpreted the question. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: Its really strange. It returns true for www.yahoo.com and false for www.google.com

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: I want you to read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php#70401). This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @BhavikShah: Yes, that's exactly the problem. But why? Is it simply a bug that the php guys did not manage to fix in the last 6 years?